# 4D Dirac delta differential relation

Tags: general-relativity, dirac-delta-distributions

I'm self teaching from the Anthony Zee Book "Einstein Gravity in a Nutshell", and I came across the following expression.
$$\partial_\mu\delta^{(4)}(x-q_a(\tau_a))=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}\delta^{(4)}(x-q_a(\tau_a))=-\frac{\partial}{\partial q^\mu_a}\delta^{(4)}(x-q_a(\tau_a))$$
where $x$ is a position in 4-space, $\delta^{(4)}$ is the delta function in 4-space, $q_a$ is the wordline of particle $a$, and $\tau_a$ is the proper time of particle $a$.  I'm having some trouble seeing how the middle term is equivalent to the third term.  My only guess is that for some reason $\frac{\partial q_a^\mu}{\partial x^\mu}$ is somehow equal to negative one, but I can't see why.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation Zee uses here is a fancy version of the following:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x } f( x - y ) = 
- \frac{\partial}{\partial y } f( x - y ).
$$

Can you see how this comes about?
Hint: rename the variable $x-y$ as $z$ and use the chain rule.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on this, because I've tried carrying this out two ways
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x-y)=\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)f(x-y)$$ and $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x-y)=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f(x-y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial(x-y)}f(x-y)$$  neither of which give the correct answer.  I feel like I've forgotten some really elementary calc here.

Comment: @Redcrazyguy hint: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f = $$\frac{\partial(x-y)}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial (x-y)} f$ and likewise for $y$.

Comment: So is it basically carrying it out for x and carrying it out for y, and then comparing and seeing that one is the negative of the other?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.